# Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string while trying to console.log wp_get_nav_menu_items

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to fetch items from currently assigned menu. Wordpress documentation says wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu) returns array of menu items. Just to test have a fetched proper menu items I wanted some kind of output. Coming from JS I tried to console log it like this:

`$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items(3);
    foreach ($menu as $menuItems) {
    ?> <script>
           console.log(<?php echo $menuItems?>);
       </script>
<?php
}`

Afterwards I get error on line where I'm console logging $menuItems:

> "Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string"

Is there any other way to log on frontend or to see the contents of $menu variable?

I also tried to echo $menu directly but not working.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `$menuItems` is an array of objects. You can't echo objects.

Comment: I just figured it out meanwhile. Small problem actually. Thanks @JacobPeattie on confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured that using `print_r` will output array via `console.log`